# "Unlike" non-diffeomorphic homeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology, diffeomorphism

We know that homeomorphic (topological isomorphisms) manifolds are not necessarily diffeomorphic  (smooth isomorphisms).

We know that  diffeomorphic  (smooth isomorphisms) manifolds are necessarily homeomorphic (topological isomorphisms).

However [Wikipedia had a statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism#Homeomorphism_and_diffeomorphism):

> [Unlike non-diffeomorphic homeomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism#Homeomorphism_and_diffeomorphism), it is relatively difficult to find a pair of homeomorphic manifolds that are not diffeomorphic.

What is the emphasis on this "Unlike" on this "Unlike non-diffeomorphic homeomorphisms"? I do not know the logic of this emphasis?

It seems that according to @Eric Wofsey,

(1) "it is very easy to find an example of a homeomoprhism that is not a diffeomorphism."

(2) "it is relatively difficult to find a pair of homeomorphic manifolds that are not diffeomorphic."

Could you write an answer and explain why?

Comment: It's just saying that it is very easy to find an example of a homeomoprhism that is not a diffeomorphism.

Comment: But Wiki also said the following sentence which implies the opposite attitude: "it is relatively difficult to find a pair of homeomorphic manifolds that are not diffeomorphic."

Comment: So I am confused the Wiki tones on two sentences are opposite. One says easy, another says difficult

Comment: That is not the same as what I wrote.  "Homeomorphism" is not the same as "pair of homeomorphic manifolds" and "difffeomorphism" is not the same as "pair of diffeomorphic manifolds".

Comment: Thanks - I think you got the point of my confusion. Could you write an answer and explain why? (1) "it is very easy to find an example of a homeomoprhism that is not a diffeomorphism." (2) "it is relatively difficult to find a pair of homeomorphic manifolds that are not diffeomorphic."

Comment: @Eric Wofsey Could anyone explained why above? (1) and (2). many thanks!

Comment: Exotic $\Bbb{R}^4$ or exotic $\Bbb{S}^7$, you can search them on wikipedia.

Comment: Or the smooth Poincaré's conjecture in dimension 4.

Comment: I know Exotic ℝ4 or exotic 7 from the context, but I do not know how these fit into  (1) and (2) respectively. Can you write an answer?

Comment: @EricWofsey basically it's easy to show a homeo between smooth manifolds isn't a diffeo, but it's hard to show (that even though) a homeo between smooth manifolds (may not itself be a diffeo, doesn't mean that it) can't be *replaced* by a diffeo? Sounds like *replaced* is the key term here. I can say $f: N \to M$ is homeo and then most likely it's not a diffeo but then most likely there's some $g: N \to M$ that is a diffeo? / to OP: great question!

Answer (score 3):

1. It is very easy to give examples of homeomorphisms between smooth manifolds which are not diffeomorphisms. For instance, the map  $f: {\mathbb R}\to  {\mathbb R}$  given by the formula $f(x)=x^3$ is a homeomorphism but is not a diffeomorphism. To see that $f$ is not a diffeomorphism, note that $f'(0)=0$, while a diffeomorphism has to have invertible derivative at each point. Alternatively, $f^{-1}(y)=y^{1/3}$ which is not differentiable at $0$. I leave it to you to verify that $f$ is a homeomorphism, you just need to check that both  $f(x)=x^3$ and $f^{-1}(y)=y^{1/3}$ are continuous functions.
2. In contrast, it is hard to give examples (and even harder to prove) of two smooth manifolds which are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic. In the known examples, it is not even obvious that two manifolds are homeomorphic to each other (this usually relies upon some theorems and the existence of a homeomorphism is not proven by writing down a formula). Once you prove that two manifolds are homeomorphic, you are then faced with the challenge that there is not diffeomorphism between the manifolds. The fact that some homeomorphism between two manifolds is not a diffeomorphism does not mean that there is no other map which will be a diffeomorphism. Look at  the example in Part 1: In fact, the identity map is a diffeomorphism from ${\mathbb R}$ to itself.

Comment: basically it's easy to show a homeo between smooth manifolds isn't a diffeo, but it's hard to show (that even though) a homeo between smooth manifolds (may not itself be a diffeo, doesn't mean that it) can't be *replaced* by a diffeo? Sounds like *replaced* is the key term here. I can say $f: N \to M$ is homeo and then most likely it's not a diffeo but then most likely there's some $g: N \to M$ that is a diffeo?

Comment: @BCLC: That's what I said.

Comment: aha note that my comment actually has 2 question marks. the 1st is the 'basically' but the 2nd is about the word 'replaced' so yes also? right yeah ok. thanks.